# DAX formula to sum individual rows by a given date and show it in a Card

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, aggregation

I am trying to sum the inventory units as of a given date (driven by a slicer) and put it in a Card.

`Measure = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Inv[TY Inv] ), 'DailySales'[Like Date] )`

I have this but seems to add all dates instead of one day

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Measure = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Inv[TY Inv] ), 'DailySales'[Like Date] = SELECTEDVALUE('DailySales'[Like Date]))
```

Comment: Thank you!. The code works when used in the DailySales table retrieving a different column.  However, I am still not getting the desired result for the intended table, I get about 9 times the amount I get when adding  the numbers in Excel.  I am not sure if the table relationships have anything to do with it.

Comment: When you say "By a given date" - do you mean on that date? So, "show me the sales for the date in the slicer" or do you mean "Show me a running total of the sales since that selected date"? (or up to the selected date)

Comment: A specific date only, not running total

Comment: I figured it out, I did have a "faulty" relationship between the tables. Thanks again Pieter